# How can I pass User Id back from Shopify's oAuth to my website?

Tags: rest, oauth, shopify

I am using Shopify's OAuth for developing a custom Shopify public app and the OAuth part is working fine. I have used the `state` parameter to include the user id in the nonce value and then capture the user id from there so that I know which user to save that access token for. However, this seems really hacky to me. What is the standard way of doing it, ie capturing user id(User is a "user" on my application backend. The user id is his id for my application, not his shopify user ID) in this case? I am making the application fully REST API based so I cannot use sessions here. What is the general approach?

Here's the Shopify documentation on OAuth implementation. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you define what a User is? With that out of the way, maybe someone can help you. As it stands, there is no such thing as a User ID unless you are speaking of a ShopifyPlus EASDK implementation whereby Shopify tells you the staff account using the App. There are no other users. So best you let everyone know what you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidLazar sorry should have made it clearer. User is the user on my own application backend who runs a shopify site, not their shopify user id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I don't think there's a more efficient/secure/non-hacky way of doing this other than how you're currently doing it. Ultimately you'd have to send something to Shopify, that Shopify then turns around and send back to you.

I'm doing a similar thing using the **state** parameter, but I'm encrypting the value (security by obscurity?) when sending, and decrypting when received. In my case, it's not a user id I'm using but a session id.